# Is there an easy way to force Windows to calculate text extents using a fixed DPI value, instead of the current DPI setting?

Tags: windows, layout, graphics, crystal-reports, dpi

I am wondering if there is an easy way to calculate the text extent of a string (similar to **[GetTextExtentPoint32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144938%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)**), but allows me to specify the DPI to use in the calcuation. In other words, is there a function that does exactly what **GetTextExtentPoint32** does, but allows me to pass the DPI as a parameter, or a way to "trick" **GetTextExtentPoint32** into using a DPI that I can specify?

Before you ask "Why on earth do you want to do that?", I'll try to explain, but bear with me, the reasons behind this request are somewhat involved.

Ultimately, this is for a custom word-wrap algorithm that breaks a long string into smaller blocks of text that need to fit neatly on a Crystal Report with complex text layout requirements (it mimics the paper form used by police officers to file criminal complaints, so the state is in charge of the layout, not us, and it has to match the paper form almost exactly).

It's impossible for Crystal Reports to lay this text out properly without help (the text has to fit inside a small box on one page, followed by "standard-sized" continuation pages if the text overflows the small block), so I wrote code to break the text into multiple "blocks" that are stored in the reporting database and then rendered individually by the report.

Given the required dimensions (in logical inches), and the font information, the code first fits the text to the required width by inserting line breaks, then breaks it into correctly-size blocks based on the text height. The algorithm uses VB6's **TextHeight** and **TextWidth** functions to calculate extents, which returns the same results that the **GetTextExtentPoint32** function would  (I checked).

This code works great when the display is set to 96dpi, but breaks at 120 DPI: Some lines end up with more words in them they would have had at 96 DPI.

For example, "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" might break as follows:

**At 96  DPI**

> The quick brown fox jumps over
>   the lazy dog

**At 120 DPI**

> The quick brown fox jumps over the
>   lazy dog

This text is then further broken up by Crystal Reports, since the first line no longer fits in the corresponding text field on the report, so the actual report output looks like this:

> The quick brown fox jumps over
>   the
>   lazy dog

At first, I thought I could compensate for this by scaling the results of **TextHeight** and **TextWidth** down by 25%, but apparently life isn't so simple: it seems numerous rounding errors creep in (and possibly other factors?), so that the text extent of any given string is never *exactly* 25% larger at 120 DPI compared to 96 DPI. I didn't expect it to scale perfectly, but it's not even close at times (in one test, the width at 120 DPI was only about 18% bigger than at 96 DPI).

This doesn't happen to any text on the report that is handled directly by Crystal Report: it seems to do a very good job of scaling everything so that the report is laid out exactly the same at 96 DPI and 120 DPI (and even 144 DPI). Even when printing the report, the text is printed exactly as it appears on the screen (i.e. it truly seems to be WYSIWYG).

Given all of this, since I know my code works at 96 DPI, I should be able to fix the problem by calculating all my text extents at 96 DPI, even if Windows is currently using a different DPI setting.

Put another way, I want the result of my **FitTextToRect** function to return the same output at any DPI setting, by forcing the text extents to be calculated using 96 DPI. This should all work out since I'm converting the extents back to inches and then comparing them against required width and height in inches. I think it just so happens that 96 DPI produces more accurate results than 120 DPI when converting back and forth between pixels and inches.

I've been pouring over the Windows **[Font and Text Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144821%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)**, seeing if could roll my own function to calculate text extent at a given DPI, looking at **[GetTextMetrics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144941%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)** and other functions to see how easy or difficult this might be to do. If there is an easier way to accomplish this, I'd love to know before I start creating my own versions of existing Windows API functions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a much simpler solution. It took me awhile to convince myself that it really does makes sense. The solution was so obvious I feel almost silly posting it here.

Ultimately, what I really want is for my **FitTextToRect** function to produce the same text layout at *any* DPI setting. It turns out, in order to make this happen, it's actually *easier* to measure everything in pixels. Since any other unit of measure will by definition take the current DPI setting into account, using anything other than pixels can throw things off.

The "trick" then is to force all the calculations to work out to the same result they would have had at 96 DPI. However, instead of calculating text extents first and then scaling them down, which adds significant error to the calculations, you can get more accurate results (i.e. the results will be equal or near equal at any DPI) if you temporarily scale the *font size* down before calculating any text extents. Note that that original font size is still used in the print preview and in the printed output.

This works because of the fact that Windows internally measures font size in *device units*, which for the screen, means pixels. The font's "point size" is converted to pixels by the application that let you select the font, using the current DPI setting:

```
font_height_in_pixels = (point_size * current_dpi / 72)
```

That is, Windows never deals directly with the font's point size: it's always dealing with pixels. As a result, it calculates text extents in terms of pixels as well.

This means you can work out a scaling factor based on the current DPI and font point size that will scale the font down to a new point size which always comes out to the same number of pixels at any DPI (I used 96 as my "baseline" DPI):

```
scaled_point_size = (point_size * 96 / current_dpi)
```

By effectively forcing the font to fit the same number of pixels at any DPI, this ensures that text extents will be the same at any DPI, and therefore the algorithm will lay the text out the same way at any DPI.

The only other thing I needed to do was ensure that the height and width parameters passed to the function, which are measured in inches, got converted to pixels correctly. I couldn't use VB6's existing inches-to-pixels conversion function, since it takes the current DPI into account (which would create inconsistent results, since the text height and width is "normalized" to 96dpi), so instead I just multiplied the height and width by 96, which converts them to what their pixel measurements would be at 96 DPI.

Answer (score 1):

GetTextMetrics accepts a DC.  It uses the DPI settings from that DC (for example, you couldn't possibly use screen settings and expect data to come out formatted acceptably for a printer).

So all you need to do is supply a DC with the right DPI.  <strike>I think you might be able to directly control the DPI of a metafile DC.</strike>

Metafiles are vector graphics so they don't even look like they have DPI.

You can control DPI with [`CreateDIBitmap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183491.aspx), but then there's no way to get a matching DC.  You could see if the DPI changes if you select that DIB into a memory DC (`CreateCompatibleDC`).

Or you could use GDI+, create a Bitmap with the desired DPI, use the Graphics constructor that operates on an Image, and then that Graphics will have the right DPI so GDI+ text measurement functions would then use your DPI of choice.

Comment: I will look into this. I don't know how Crystal actually renders text, because it always seems to place text breaks in the same place regardless of the screen DPI settings, in both the preview and the printed output. Somehow it manages to avoid the rounding errors that are throwing my function off, it seems. OTOH, since it's simply displaying text, I assume it's using `DrawText`, which maybe is simply better at inserting word breaks such that the same text breaks the same way at any DPI. MSDN does say other graphics functions maintain an "error term" to compensate for rounding errors.